# C# Assign an object from class B to class A

Tags: c#

I have Two Classes.

**Class A:**

```
public class A {
    prop string p1  { get; set; }
    prop string p2  { get; set; }
    prop string p3  { get; set; }
}
```

**Class B:**

```
public class B {
    prop string p1  { get; set; }
    prop string p3  { get; set; }
}
```

Now assume we have an object from class `B` and we want to assign it to object from class `A`.

```
B b_obj = new B(){
     p1 = "something",
     p2 = "something else"
} 

A a_obj = new A(){
    p1 = b_obj.p1,
    p3 = b_obj.p3,
}
```

*I think the above solution is not best way.*

What is **best practice** to assign `b_obj` to another object from class `A`?

> Tip : All property in `class B` has a similar property in `class A`

Comment: You could create a copy constructor in `B` that takes an instance of `A`. But if all properties are similar the question arises why there are two classes at all

Comment: @TimSchmelter - which will end up with same "mapping" logic

Comment: This is called "object to object mapping".  
You can do this manually, or use third party solution like Automapper.

Comment: For a broader solution, look at tools like AutoMapper

Comment: @Fabio: sure, but only once and encapsulated in `B` not everywhere.

Comment: I don't know how exactly automapper works (reflection?) but I'd just serialize `B` and then deserialize it as `A`. Obviously serialized data shouldn't contain type info or you have to somehow override it (in case of `TypeNameHandling.Auto` json it would be custom `JsonBinder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use automapper
http://automapper.org/
Then you can use it like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
var a = ...
var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<B>(a);
```

Comment: I think it is a better solution than Murad Garibzada's, because of the performance. You can then use this solution within cast operator/extension methods (see @InBetween answer which is more complete than mine) to shorten your code base.

Comment: I don't like it. It is not refactoring safe. If I refactor __B.p1__ to __B.q1__ the property names do not line up and I may get an obscure runtime failure or data corruption rather than a compile time failure. To be sure you don't get errors through refactoring then you have to write a unit test using https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation

Comment: @bradgonesurfing I provided basic syntax. If you want compiler help, you can use extended syntax for mapping rules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985000/how-to-use-automapper-formember

Answer (score 5):

You can always implement an implicit or explicit cast operator:

```
public class B
{
     public static explicit operator A(B b)
     {
          return new A() {
                           p1 = b_obj.p1,
                           p3 = b_obj.p3,
                         }
     }

     //...
 }
```

And now, you can simply write any time you need an `A` from a `B`:

```
var a = (A)b;
```

If you don't have access to either `A` or `B` then you could implement an extension method:

```
public static A ToA(this B b)
{
    return ...
}
```

And the use would be similar:

```
var a = b.ToA();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (see denisv's answer) which provides mappings between classes based on name. You can then customize your mappings if you want to.

You can also write some extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public A ToA(this B b)
    {
        return new A() 
        {
            p1 = b_obj.p1,
            p3 = b_obj.p3,
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all initialize B class and set values. Then create such a class:

```
public static void CopyPropertyValues(object source, object  destination)
{
var destProperties = destination.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var sourceProperty in source.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    foreach (var destProperty in destProperties)
    {
        if (destProperty.Name == sourceProperty.Name && 
    destProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(sourceProperty.PropertyType))
        {
            destProperty.SetValue(destination, sourceProperty.GetValue(
                source, new object[] { }), new object[] { });

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and pass A and B class to this class as Parameter

Comment: While this answer is a good answer, you have to know that this uses reflexion and has an impact on the performance.

Comment: But it is best way, and you don't care about which fields exist in classes, it is enough to know both classes properties are same.

Comment: As I said, it is a good answer. Is just warned the OP about the performance impact. I am not the one who downvotes your post.