# Cannot Convert from class to class in C# on different projects in the same solutions

Tags: c#

Cannot Convert From ElasticCoreWebApi.Controllers.AcquirerController.AcquirerReportParameters to ElasticCoreWebApi.BLL.ElasticSettledTranaction.AcquirerReportParameter

ElasticCoreWebApi has Reference of ElasticCoreWebApi.BLL operation

**ElasticCoreWebApi.AcquirerController has the class**

```
   public class AcquiringReportParameters
        {
            public string reportname { get; set; }
            public int merchantId { get; set; }
            public string branchCodes { get; set; }
            public string fromDate { get; set; }
            public string toDate { get; set; }
            public string merchantName { get; set; }
            public string batchNo { get; set; }
            public string terminalId { get; set; }
            public string merchantNumber { get; set; }
            public string merchantBranchName { get; set; }
            public string dRCR { get; set; }
            public string mID { get; set; }
            public int pageSize { get; set; }
            public int pageIndex { get; set; }
        }
```

In Acquirer controller i am calling the second method and passing the parameters like this i have data mapped in the class

```
    AcquiringReportParameters parameters = new AcquiringReportParameters();

    ElasticSettlementTransactionBLL ElasticBLL = new ElasticSettlementTransactionBLL();
 
    *var test = await ElasticBLL.GetSettledParameterTransaction(parameters);*
*I am getting error here in the parameter*
```

**ElasticCoreWebApi.BLL.ElasticSettledTransaction.cs  has the class**

```
  public class AcquiringReportParameters
        {
            public string reportname { get; set; }
            public int merchantId { get; set; }
            public string branchCodes { get; set; }
            public string fromDate { get; set; }
            public string toDate { get; set; }
            public string merchantName { get; set; }
            public string batchNo { get; set; }
            public string terminalId { get; set; }
            public string merchantNumber { get; set; }
            public string merchantBranchName { get; set; }
            public string dRCR { get; set; }
            public string mID { get; set; }
            public int pageSize { get; set; }
            public int pageIndex { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is the method which i was calling

```
        public async Task<string> GetSettledParameterTransaction(AcquiringReportParameters parameters)
```

Comment: They are different types? `new 
 ElasticCoreWebApi.Controllers.AcquirerController.AcquirerReportParameters.AcquiringReportParameters()`

Comment: If A and B are different types, then converting A to B require some [additional work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42622615/1997232).

Comment: no both are class and same as that of the one class to the other class

Comment: If they are *look same*, they are still different types if defined in different places.

Comment: Even if they are identical in every way, they are still two independent classes. You will need to map one to the other, or have one declaration and some sort of shared library ?

Comment: then what can i do??

Comment: Simply read comments above. Carefully. They contain answers.

Comment: The fastest (but not the best) solution to make this code work is to replace the type of the expected parameter in your method `GetSettledParameterTransaction` to `dynamic`.